# What's the name of this theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

What's the name of this theorem
in right-angled triangle $ABC$, occur:

$|AC|^2=|CD|×|CB|$

$|AD|^2=|DC|×|DB|$

$|AB|^2=|BD|×|BC|$

Please send me references about this theorem

Comment: What is $D$? $\ \ $

Comment: In Italy these are called "Euclid's Theorems for right triangles", but I haven't found anything like that on the web.

Comment: @PatrickStevens It's the foot of the altitude relative to the hypotenuse.

Comment: Those are fairly straightforward similarities, and I've never known them under a special name. FWIW the middle one is referred to as the "*right triangle altitude theorem*" or "*geometric mean theorem*" in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem).